# Is there a common name for the document for new project requirements?

Tags: professionalism, project-management, projects

I would like to push in our company so any new project goes with a document stating things in the line of:

- Economic savings of the new project
- Saving in working hours of the new project

This idea of adding those requirements for a new project has surely an name and a methodology, but I haven't been able to find any lead.

Comment: You're looking for a Cost-Benefit Analysis. You should also consider asking this question in the project management stack.

Comment: I suggest that what you have listed are not project requirements, they are project goals, and best fit in a charter document or business case.

Comment: I know this as a Project Initiation Document.

Comment: Hi @GregoryCurrie didn't know there was a project management stack, I'll look into that for future questions
I'm going for the bussiness case, it's just what I wanted, I am reading through the different criteria for filling them but seems just what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds awfully like what we would term a "Business Case" - which is exactly what it says on the tin, a case being made why doing this project benefits the business. This is then weighed against the costs of implementing it, both financial and in other resources (employee time etc) to decide whether it should be done, and if it is to be done what sort of priority it should be accorded.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this description, I see two types of documents that it could be.

[As described by motosubatsu](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/192814/3), it could be a business case, which describes the feasibility of building a product or executing a project and what the benefits of the successful effort would be.

A vision and scope document, among other things, contains the goals and objectives of the product or project. Savings - expressed in money, time, effort - can be an objective that could be achieved by successfully completing the work.

Both are created early in a product or project life cycle. In addition, taking an evolutionary approach to your documentation could allow for adding additional content from these types of documents, based on stakeholder needs, as the work progresses.